# Trunk replaced by another branch during svn merge

Tags: svn, merge

After a particular merge from branch to trunk, I see commit messages of the form:

### Branch '/trunk' replaced from /branches/Defect/DD9999-e72327:77712

Replacing : /core/trunk (Copy from path: /core/branches/SVDefect/DD9999-e72327, Revision, 77712)

Need help to figure out what's wrong here.

Comment: The string "replaced from" doesn't occur in the git source.  That's not a git message.  You've got some hook or another doing things apparently nobody ever pointed you at the docs for or even told you exists. Ask whoever set up your tools.

Comment: My git repo is sync with another svn repo. I guess this should be coming from there. Also the revisions are from SVN.